# Using 'value' binding in Knockoutjs gives error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I cannot get the 'value' databinding in Knockout to work. At all. It's kind of bizarre.

When I use:

```
<span data-bind="text : aValue"></span>
```

with the model:

```
{
    aValue : ko.observable("Value")
}
```

It displays the text "Value".

Replacing the span with:

```
<input data-bind:"value:aValue" />
```

Causes an error:

```
Unable to process binding "value: function (){return aValue }"
Message: jQueryInstance(...).bind is not a function
```

Comment: It would need to be observable for two-way binding, wouldn't it? What did your code look like when you tried that? Is the case mismatch just a typo in your question? (`avalue` versus `aValue`)

Comment: @nnnnnn That was indeed just a typo. I fixed the question up a little.

Comment: A minimal version of your code worked for me with two-way binding (update on change/blur) here: https://jsfiddle.net/tyctm6f0/ (Regarding your error message, you're using jQuery too?)

Comment: Can you share a working sample. That would be help for us to debug and help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem existed between keyboard and chair; I was loading the slim + minified version of jQuery which was causing Knockout to break.